# Denied check-in baggage

Tags: luggage

I paid in advance for checked-in luggage, which satisfied the airline's regulations about max dimensions, weight and content (various bicycle parts plus hand tools). Yet, at the airport (Europe, inside EU) they insisted that it should instead go as sport equipment and that I have to pay extra. I denied that and they called some higher authority inside their company and that person hadn't been answering until it was the last moment for me to board the flight.

So, I was forced to leave my luggage and flew without it (to be on that flight was most important to me).
They first printed the labels (tags) but eventually took them away from my luggage, yet I managed to take a photo of them and to make a PIR report when the plane landed.

I wonder if the airline is obliged to pay me some compensation, if I should also contact somebody else, if I also can count on starting a legal process (in court) about it and which court should be responsible, and so on.

I would appreciate any clever advice and guidance, thanks in advance.

Comment: What country did this happen in, and what airline was this?

Comment: Which airport? And (for clarity) who did you pay in advance? How did the baggage check-in at the airport know what was inside your suitcase? Was it in effect a entire dismantled bike, or just various parts that put together would not make a rideable bike?

Comment: What does the airline’s baggage policy on bikes say?

Comment: Was is an actual suitcase/travel bag containing bike components and tools or was it a disassembled or folded bike vaguely wrapped? And do I understand correctly that in the end you just abandoned it there?